# Example stack in javascript, need clarification on 'this' usage

Tags: javascript

I found this example and I'm unable to understand how it works:

```js
function Stack() {
  this.top = null;
}
    
Stack.prototype.push = function(val) {
  this.top = {
    data : val,
    next : this.top
  }
}
    
var S1 = new Stack();
S1.push(1);
S1.push(2);
console.log(S1);
```

why is 'next : this.top' resolving into the previous push's 'this.top' object? and not just returning null?

Comment: Whenever `.push` is called a new object is assigned to `this.top`. Hence *before* the assignment, `this.top` refers to the object created in the *previous* `.push` call.

Comment: *next* should be *previous*. ;-)

Comment: oh.. that's a really good answer @FelixKling.  I kept thinking that the object was overwritten  BEFORE the reference could be made to the previous 'this.top'.  That is what confused me.  Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Ah, I see. Whatever is on the right hand side of the assignment is evaluated before the assignment takes place, that includes resolving `this.top` to a value that is assigned to the `next` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a function is called as a method of an object, its this is set to the object the method is called on.

you can see this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method) for more details

Answer (score 1):

`this` in JavaScript is a game changer and it should be taken care of. The thing with `this` is that it references the context of the function you invoked.

In this case, when `.push` is invoked this will reference the Stack object instance.

Btw `console.log` prints as it is being resolved, but you can't expect to have ti resolved at that point in time.